# Disable navigating to next page if inputField isn't filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to prevent the user from accessing the next page if there is an empty
  inputField. The alert does show when the field is empty and i click the button, but i can click 'ok' and i get taken to the next page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){

        function checkFilled(inputField) {

            if(inputField.value.length > 1) {
                return true; 
                }
            else {
                    alert('field1 is not filled in');
                    $("#button1").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();     
                    });                                 
                    return false; 
                }
            };  

            document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function() { 

            var field1 = document.getElementById('field1');
            checkFilled(field1);    
            };
        };  

</script>






<input type="text" name="field1"  id="field1"/>

    <a href="nextpage.html">

        <div id="button1"></div>

    </a>
```

Comment: How can the alert be showing at all? `checkFilled()` is never actually called. Does your code differ from the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used an [a tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) where the `href` attribute is set and gets you immediately to the next page, although the `inputField` is empty. This should do what you want:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  function checkFilled(inputField) {
    if(inputField.value.length > 1) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      alert('field1 is not filled in');
      return false;
    }
  };
  document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function() {
    var field1 = document.getElementById('field1');
    return checkFilled(field1);
  };
};
```

```html
<input type="text" name="field1"  id="field1"/>
<form action="nextpage.html">
    <input id="button1" type="submit" value="next">
</form>
```

Or if you prefer to use an `a` tag instead of a button:

```js
function checkFilled() {
  if(document.getElementById("field1").value.length > 1) {
    window.location.href="nextpage.html";
  }
  else {
    alert('field1 is not filled in');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="field1"  id="field1"/>
<a href="#" onclick="checkFilled();">next</a>
```